# Check if surface area is big enough to create volume

Tags: volume, area

Given volume and surface area only, how can I check whether the surface area is enough to create the specified volume?

If the [lowest area to volume ratio](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/715341/highest-volume-area-ratio) suggests that a sphere is the optimum container, does that mean I just use the formulae for sphere area and volume and compare the radius?

What if the container must be a cuboid? What if none or one side of the cuboid is given?

Comment: The most efficient cuboid is the cube. Note that the sphere has *lowest* area to volume ratio.

Comment: oh.. then the most efficient area is the square?

Comment: In two dimensions, for given perimeter, the largest area is obtained by using a circle. But for given perimeter, the rectangle of largest area is a square.

Comment: Thanks @AndréNicolas if you write all that as answer, I will mark it as accepted.

Comment: Someone may wish to give a thorough answer. If you are given the volume $V$, then by the usual formula, for a sphere we have $r=\left(\frac{3V}{4\pi}\right)^{1/3}$, so the surface area is $4\pi\left(\frac{3V}{4\pi}\right)^{2/3}$. If that much (or more) surface area is available, you can make the object of volume $V$. If less surface area is available, you can't.